# ToString Applied to the Number Type

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

i read the ecmascript 9.8.1 section ToString Applied to the Number Type,
but i don't know what it means.

> The operator ToString converts a number m to string format as follows:
>
> 1. If m is NaN, return the string "NaN".
> 2. If m is +0 or -0, return the string "0".
> 3. If m is less than zero, return the string concatenation of the string "-" and ToString(-m).
> 4. If m is infinity, return the string "Infinity".
> 5. Otherwise, let n, k, and s be integers such that k >= 1, 10k-1<= s <10k, the number value for s * 10n-k is m, and k is as small as
>      possible. Note that k is the number of digits in the decimal
>      representation of s, that s is not divisible by 10, and that the least
>      significant digit of s is not necessarily uniquely determined by these
>      criteria.
> 6. If k <= n <= 21, return the string consisting of the k digits of the decimal representation of s (in order, with no leading zeroes),
>      followed by n k occurrences of the character '0'.
> 7. If 0 < n <= 21, return the string consisting of the most significant n digits of the decimal representation of s, followed by a
>      decimal point '. ', followed by the remaining k-n digits of the
>      decimal representation of s.
> 8. If -6 < n <= 0, return the string consisting of the character '0', followed by a decimal point '. ', followed by -n occurrences of the
>      character '0', followed by the k digits of the decimal representation
>      of s.
> 9. Otherwise, if k = 1, return the string consisting of the single digit of s, followed by lowercase character 'e', followed by a plus
>      sign '+ ' or minus sign '-' according to whether n-1 is positive or
>      negative, followed by the decimal representation of the integer
>      abs(n-1) (with no leading zeros).
> 10. Return the string consisting of the most significant digit of the decimal representation of s, followed by a decimal point '. ',
>       followed by the remaining k-1 digits of the decimal representation of
>       s, followed by the lowercase character 'e', followed by a plus sign '+
>       ' or minus sign '-' according to whether n-1 is positive or negative,
>       followed by the decimal representation of the integer abs(n-1) (with
>       no leading zeros).

can somebody explain the algorithm to me or give me a blog about the ToString Applied to the Number Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification is made for developers of JavaScript *engines*. It describes details of the engines' internals, that may not be relevant to JS developers.

Particularly, the `ToString` operation can not be called directly from JS. You can get *almost* the same effect by this function:

```
  function ToString(input) {
      return '' + input;
  }
```

Now [section 9.8.1](http://es5.github.com/#x9.8.1) simply describes what should happen when a number is passed into this function.

Points 5. to 10. make sure that very large numbers or numbers with many decimal places are stringified to scientific notation like so:

```
ToString(100000000000000000000) // "100000000000000000000"
ToString(10000000000000000000000) // "1e+22"
ToString(.000003001) // ".000003001"
ToString(.0000003001) // "3.001e-7"
ToString(100000000.00000003001) // "100000000.00000003"
ToString(1000000000.00000003001) // "1000000000"
```

---

As for 5.: It can be deduced that

If `m` is an integer, `n` is the number of digits of `m`. `s` is the integer that results from stripping all trailing zeroes, and `k` is the number of digits in `s`.

So for example

- `m = 100000000000000000000` would yield `s = 1`, `k = 1`, `n = 21`, thus point 6. returns `"100000000000000000000"`
- `m = 10000000000000000000000` means `s = 1`, `k = 1`, `n = 23`, thus point 9. returns `"1e+22"`

Comment: thanks for your reply. according to 9.8.1 when the number value m is 100000000000000000000, n = k =21, s = 100000000000000000000, so m is converted to String according to the point 5 when the number value m is 10000000000000000000000, n = k = 23, s= 10000000000000000000000 is m converted to String according to the point 10?

Comment: @user1039304 I edited my answer to clarify point 5.

Comment: i forgot that s is not divisible by 10...
so m = 100000000.00000003001 would yield s = 10000000000000003001,
k = 20, n = 9,thus point 7,return "100000000.00000003001"
am i right?

Comment: Not quite. The thing is, the condition "the Number value for s×10^(n−k) is m" in 5. does not *exactly* mean "s*10^(n-k)==m". Instead, it accounts for rounding errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004

Answer (score 0):

you can get the best tutorial about toString at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

hope it will help .

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to convert a number to a string, just use concatenation:

```
var number = 1;
var numberAsString = '' + number;
```